# How to pass edittext value to another activity's textview

Tags: java, android

i want to send value from one activity's edit-text to another activity's text-view.I have written following code but when i am running the program than it is showing nothing.so can you help on this...

***Home.java***

```
Intent in = new Intent(Home.this, Splash.class);
                    String Data= UserName.getText().toString();
                    in.putExtra("text",Data);
                    startActivity(in);
```

***splash.java***

```
Intent in = new Intent(Splash.this, SearchData.class);
                    UserWelcome.setText(in.getStringExtra("text"));
                    startActivity(in);
```

here **username** is the **edittext** and **userwelcome** is the **textview**.

Comment: change `in.getStringExtra("text")` to `getIntent().getStringExtra("text")`

Comment: which activity is called first , splash or Home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change in `splash`

```
 UserWelcome.setText(in.getStringExtra("text"));
```

to

```
 UserWelcome.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("text"));
```

Answer (score 0):

In splash.java do this..

```
UserWelcome.setText(getIntent.getStringExtra("text"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace this in **splash.java**

```
 Intent in = new Intent(Splash.this, SearchData.class);
 UserWelcome.setText(in.getStringExtra("text"));
 startActivity(in);
```

with

```
 UserWelcome.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("text"));
```